# Post to web api the object is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, null

This is the post method in my api controller

```
[HttpPost]
[CheckModelForNull]
[ValidateModelState]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] DepModel depModel)
{
    try
    {

        var entity = TheDepModelFactory.Parse(depModel);

        if (entity == null) Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not read object from body");

        TheDepRepository.Post(entity);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, TheDepModelFactory.Create(entity));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
public class DepModel
{

        public int dep_Id { get; set; }
        public string dep_name { get; set; }

}
```

When I send a post request using fiddler it is added to the database but when I use my application it dose not work.

I download application in the tutorial 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-9
and when I run the application I gave me the same problem you can add to the database from fiddler but not from the application view?!!

I think it is something in the configuration not in the code but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

set the correct 'Content-Type' in the header

Comment: The application is working fine in another computer the problem is in my computer not in the application. I use Windows 8.1 64 bit, Visual Studio 2012 update 1. and I disable the firewall in case it is blocking the request but that didn't fix the problem.